# When checkout of my ecommerce website by Wordpress & Woocommerce showing Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, checkout, elementor

I have set up a WooCommerce website, and when customer checkout for purchasing anything showing Internal Server Error. My domain is sheelashop.com; I uninstall and re-install all theme and plugin, but the result is same. I install an ecommerce website by creating subdomain sheeza.sheelashop.com and this is working. Can anybody make a solution?

I try by myself with uninstall WordPress, theme and plugins but the result is same

Comment: You need to enable debug log and share the errors you get. https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/